# React.js Previewing an Image with input type file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, input

Currently I am trying to preview an image up on an upload of an image file. I can recieve the image, and console log however I can not display it in the img tag.

Here is the way that I am trying to render them:

```js
<input type='file' id="uploadImage" onChange={this.handleImageChange} className="upload-input" />
<label htmlFor="uploadImage" className="upload-image-button">Choose An Image</label>
{this.state.imagePreview[0] ?
  <img src={this.state.imagePreview[0]} alt="" className="image-preview" /> 
  :
  <img alt="" className="image-preview" />
}
```

Here are my state and my handle on change method for the input:

```js
state = {
  imagePreview: {}
}

handleImageChange = async (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.files)
  await this.setState({ imagePreview: e.target.files })
  console.log(this.state.imagePreview)
}
```

Here are my console logs for the files:
[image]

Comment: I have tried to do variation of the different attributes in the files like < this.state.imagePreview[0].name > however, it was still not helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a `FileReader` object, in order to get the base64 data and apply it to the source of the image tag.

Also, I don't see any need for this to be an `async` function (unless, for the sake of brevity, you left out a promise you're working with).

From the code you've presented, something like this should work:

```
handleImageChange(event) {

   const file = event.target.files[0];
   const reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = function(event) {
     // The file's text will be printed here, if you want to see the base64
     console.log(event.target.result)
     // Set state with base64 data
     this.setState({ imagePreview: e.target.result })
   };

   reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Html (or jsx) would look something like so:

```
<img src={this.state.imagePreview} alt="" className="image-preview" />
```

Comment: for some reason it is giving me an error saying "TypeError: this.setState is not a function". also the async is for an api call that I will be making after I resolve this issue

Comment: You've got to bind the method's context in your constructor. In your constructor, add this line of code: `this.handleImageChange = this.handleImageChange.bind(this)` I'm guessing you're new to react. Put your research cap on :)

Comment: Yes I am new to react :) I just became an intern and had to learn it on the spot...